# Where to get Microsoft.VisualStudio.Quality.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel

Tags: .net, visual-studio, libraries

I'm trying to implement [TestRows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx) for MSTest.

It says this reference is necessary but I have no idea where to get it. When I search for it I get all kinds of programs to 'detect missing dlls'. But I already know which dll I need.

The guide contains a link to another guide where it explains how to add the references. They say all you need to do is add the reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` then all required references should be included.

When searching for this I have three options. Two with version 10.0.0.0 and one with version 10.1.0.0. But regardless of what version I choose `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Quality.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel` is not referenced.

Answer (score 0):

`dir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\*microsoft.visualstudio.quality*' /s` found the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` which seems promising. Have you tried that .DLL using that path? (not clear from the OP if you have as OP doesn't list the file paths)

There is also a  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`

Comment: Nope, hadn't tried that one, but it doesn't help. I did try the second one.

Comment: I suggest you update the OP with what files you have tried, which version and edition of VS you are using, which VS service packs, and whether you've chosen any custom installation options. Did you see this [Q&A:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37d76c2d-2b2f-4949-8dc9-a411df10fd85/what-is-the-corresponding-dll-for-microsoftvisualstudioqualitytoolscommandlinedll-in-vs2010?forum=vststest). If so please update the OP with that and other web searches you tried. I saw at least 3 other blogs w what looks like relevant info.